# os.listdir() is giving larger lists than expected

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, file

My book states that:

> Calling `os.listdir(path)` will return a list of filename strings for each file in the path argument.

I tried to get the files inside a folder which is placed on the desktop and it worked perfectly fine. Then I tried to get the files in the root folder '/' and it's giving weird results.

My root folder has 5 files which include Applications, Library, Users etc but `os.listdir('/')` gives me a list of some 20-25 list items some of which are Applications, Library, Users,**.DS_Store**, **Trashes**, **.dbfseventsd**,**.Spotlight-V100** etc. Note that the bold text list items do not seem to appear in the root folder when I manually open it.

Why is this happening and what should I do?

Comment: Those are hidden files, try enabling the show-hidden-files feature then see.

Comment: @MrGeek! Yeah!!! It did work. Thank you

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but check out ```glob``` for listing things in directories. I much prefer it to os.listdir(). e.g. ```t = glob.glob('/*')``` will give you all the items in root directly without the hidden files (of course, you must ```import glob``` first).

Comment: @JamesMcCormac I tried to install glob module using `sudo pip3 install glob` and it says that "**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glob (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for glob**"

Comment: I think it should be in Python3 by default? Try importing it?

Comment: @JamesMcCormac I am using Python 3.6 and there is no glob module over here :(

Comment: which Python 3.6? Works fine for my miniconda install ```▶ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import glob
>>>```

Comment: @JamesMcCormac Damn! It is there! I was typing in `globe` :-P . Anyway thank you so much for letting me know about `glob`

Comment: Nps :) Good luck!

Comment: @JamesMcCormac haha, even if you like glob.glob, it using listdir under the hood and is kinda overkill for just listing the one-level directory.

Comment: yea but i prefer the interface glob provides, its not really overkill if it does exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your root folder includes hidden directories or files. These begin with a `.`, and are not seen by default in the Finder or `ls`. However, `os.listdir` returns them as well.

If you want to ignore these files, you may use:

```
files = [x for x in os.listdir('/') if not x.startswith('.')]
```

---

As an extra, it is useful to know how to view these hidden files on OSX. To see them in `Finder`:

1. Open `Finder`
2. Go to your Macintosh HD folder (access this from Devices in the left column)
3. Hold down `CMD-Shift-.` (dot)

To see them in your terminal, run `ls -a /path/to/dir`.

Comment: Thanks for such an amazing answer Coldspeed! 
I typed the following code in Terminal : `$ ls -a /` But it says that `-bash: $: command not found`

Comment: @M.Hamel You gotta remove the `$`. That's a shell prompt :) Just do `ls -a`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh, code have 2 errors: you mean basename(x)?   and second, listdir returns object names inside folder and not full path. `[x for x in os.listdir('/') if not x.startswith('.')]` is enough